# Get value from Nested Object

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I am trying to get the first value for an object like:

```
{
 "_id":"123",
    "list":{"56":{"name":"Great ","amount":100,"place":"Town"},"57":{"name":"Great  2","amount":200,"place":"City"}},
    "pop":[2,3]
}
```

This is 1 object of around 100 or so. I am trying to get the `amount` from the first value of `list` property in each of the 100 objects ? i.e. so above it would be `100`

How would I do that ? I am using underscore JS ?

Comment: Your "list" is a plain object, not an array, so there is no "first" value.

Comment: Show us how those 100 objects are stored if you want to access all of them, not just one extracted example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining list as `object` . Object properties are in order of they defined, but we cannot trust its order . I think there is Chrome bug about it https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=164

the following `first` method gives first element from list object , this function will works most cases , if object is empty it will return `undefined` value.

```
var data = {
 "_id":"123",
    "list":{
        "56":{"name":"Great ","amount":100,"place":"Town"},
        "57":{"name":"Great  2","amount":200,"place":"City"}
    },
    "pop":[2,3]
};


function first( data ){

    for ( var i in data ){
        if ( data.hasOwnProperty(i) ) break;    
    }

    return data.hasOwnProperty(i) ? data[i] : undefined;
}

first( data.list ).amount;
```

If you want to keep order of list .. define them as `Array` . example

```
var data = {
 "_id":"123",
    "list":[
        {"id" : "56" ,"name":"Great ","amount":100,"place":"Town"},
        {"id" : "57" ,"name":"Great  2","amount":200,"place":"City"}
    ],
    "pop":[2,3]
};
```

and access them as `data.list[0]`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
function getFirstAmount(obj){
   for(var key in obj){
      return obj[key].amount;
   }
}
```

If you need to get all keys, you can try this

```
 function getAmounts(obj){
    var amounts = [];
    var  i = 0;
    for(var key in obj){
          amounts[i] = obj[key].amount;
          i++;
       }
    }
    return amounts;
 }

 //call function
   var firstAmount = getFirstAmount(obj.list);
```